# A string and its palindrome

Tags: memory, malloc, palindrome

The purpose of this function is to create a string concat with its palindrome. For example 
abc -> abccba

Here is my code, and the result still show the original string without any change. I reserved some spaces for the string and its palindrome, but it still does not work.

```
char *mirror(const char *str) {
    char *result = malloc(2 * strlen(str) * sizeof(char));
    int str_len = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < str_len; ++i) {
        result[i] = str[i];
    }
    for (int j = str_len; j < 2*str_len; ++j) {
        result[j] = str[2*str_len-j];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code fails to allocate for and append a *null character*.

Better to use `size_t` for array indexing and sizing.

Check for failed allocation

```
char *mirror(const char *str) {
    size_t length = strlen(str);
    char *result = malloc(2*length + 1);  // + 1 for \0
    if (result) {

      size_t r;
      for (r = 0; r < length; ++r) {
        result[r] = str[r];
      }

      size_t j = length;
      for (; r < length*2; ++r) {
        result[r] = str[--j];
      }

      result[r] = '\0';
    }
    return result;
}
```